# SFML, View и отрисовка

Tags: c++, view, sfml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, отрисовывает ли `SFML` то, что находится за пределами используемого вида?

Например, если я нарисую квадрат 1000 x 1000 спрайтов, но при этом в используемый вид попадут только 100 спрайтов, будет ли `SFML` отрисовывать то, что не попало в поле видимости?

Comment: отрисовываются те объекты, которые Вы укажите (через win.draw()). View лишь определяет, как отрисовывать их в окно, он сам не будет "отрезать" лишние (то бишь не попадающие в кадр) объекты. Поэтому, да SFML отрисовывает то, что находится за пределами используемого вида.

Comment: sfml это обёртка для opengl, соответственно решать, что рисовать, а что нет будет скорее всего видеокарта